# Can $11^{13}-1$ be divided exactly by 6?

Tags: number-theory

Can $11^{13}-1$ be divided exactly by 6?

**My solution:**
$$11^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 6$$
$$11^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod 6$$
$$11^{13} \equiv 5 \pmod 6 $$

Hence, $(11^{13}-\mathbf{5})$ can be divided exactly by 6. However, according to the solution on my book, （$11^{13}-\mathbf{1}$）can be divide exactly by 6. What's wrong?

Comment: The solution according to what?

Comment: You have shown $11^{13}-5$ can be divided by 6; so too can $11^{13}+1$. So $11^{13}-1$ cannot; $11^{1}-1=10$ cannot either.

Comment: $11^{13} - 5 \equiv 0 \mod 6$ so $11^3 - 1 \equiv 4 \mod 6$.

Comment: If you know that that $N$ is divisible by $6$, then surely you know that $N+4$ is not divisible by $6$. In particular, $N+4 = 4$ mod $6$.

Comment: $11 \equiv -1 \mod 6$ should help copmputations like this.

Comment: $11^{13}-1=34522712143930$ is not divisible by $6$.

Comment: Some books have on-line listings of errata.  Maybe yours does.

Comment: Probably $\:11^{13}\!-1\:$ is a typo for $\:11^{13}\!+1\equiv (-1)^{13}\!+1\equiv 0\pmod 6.\ \ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is already not divisible by $ 3 $; notice that
\begin{align}
11^{13} - 1 &\equiv (-1)^{13} - 1 \\
            &\equiv -1 - 1 \\
            &\equiv -2 \\
            &\equiv 1 \\
            &\not\equiv 0 \, (\text{mod} \, 3).
\end{align}

**Note** $ 11 \equiv 2 \equiv -1 \, (\text{mod} \, 3) $.

Answer (score 4):

Assume $11^{13}-1$ was divisible by $6$, then we'd have
$$11^{13}-1\equiv 0\pmod 6.$$
In other words, $11^{13}\equiv 1$. However, by your computation $11^{13}\equiv 5$, this is a contradiction because $1$ and $5$ are not congruent modulo $6$. Hence, $11^{13}-1$ is **not** divisible by $6$.

Answer (score 1):

As          $\frac {11}{6}  $  gives remainder of $5$   or $-1$ . we take $-1$ as it eases our calculation .

1) $ \frac{11^{13}}6 $  gives remainder  $-1$ .

2) $ \frac{1}6 $  gives remainder 1

FIND : RESULT $1$ - RESULT $2$

$-1 -1 = -2$  which is equal to $4 $ as $6-2 =4$

So remainder is $4$  . It means it is definitely NOT  DIVISIBLE by  6 .

.You can check your answers in one of the most trusted sites : wolframalpha , where you can do such calculation involving large numbers . 
I have done the following for you in the link below .
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=11%5E13%E2%88%921+mod+6

Even scientific calculators in computers perform, mod operation of such large numbers with ease .

These computing sites give confidence on our calculation.